# How to project specific fields from a queried document inside an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here is the document

```
formId: 123,
title:"XYZ"
eventDate:"2022-04-15T05:40:57.182Z"
responses:[
           {
            orderId:98422,
            name:"XYZ1",
            email:"a@gmal.com",
            paymentStatus:"pending",
            amount:250,
            phone:123456789
           },
           {
            orderId:98422,
            name:"XYZ1",
            email:"a@gmal.com",
            paymentStatus:"success",
            amount:250,
            phone:123456791
           }
          ]
```

I used $elemMatch to filter the array such that I get only the matched object.

```
  const response = await Form.findOne({ formId:123 }, {
            _id:0,
            title: 1,
            eventDate: 1,
            responses: {
                 $elemMatch: { orderId: 98422 },

             },
            
        })
```

But this returns all the fields inside the object present in the array "responses".

```
title:"XYZ"
eventDate:"2022-04-15T05:40:57.182Z"
responses:[
           {
            orderId:98422,
            name:"XYZ1",
            email:"a@gmal.com",
            paymentStatus:"pending",
            amount:250,
            phone:123456789
           }
          ]
```

But I want only specific fields to be returned inside the object like this

```
title:"XYZ"
eventDate:"2022-04-15T05:40:57.182Z"
responses:[
           {
       
            name:"XYZ1",
            email:"a@gmal.com",
            paymentStatus:"pending",
           }
          ]
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Query

- aggregation way to keep some members and edit them also
- map on responses if `orderId` matches keep the fields you want, the others are replaced with null
- filter to remove those nulls (members that didnt match)
- here 2 matches if you want to keep only one member of the array you can use
  `[($first ($filter ...)]`

*`$elemMatch` that you used can be combined with the `$` project operator to avoid the aggregation, but with `$` operator we get all the matching member (here you want only some fields so i think aggregation is the way)

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62599328f7e3c64c6511e18b)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"formId": {"$eq": 123}}},
 {"$project": 
   {"_id": 0,
    "title": 1,
    "eventDate": 1,
    "responses": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$responses",
        "in": 
         {"$cond": 
           [{"$eq": ["$$this.orderId", 98422]},
             {"name": "$$this.name",
              "email": "$$this.email",
              "paymentStatus": "$$this.paymentStatus"},
            null]}}}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"responses": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$responses", "cond": {"$ne": ["$$this", null]}}}}}])
```